# Position of "with a view to" in a sentence

Tags: word-order

I would like to formulate a sentence pattern that could be like:

> *"To avoid misunderstandings: the purpose of the component is not to store electricity until needed **with a view to energy recovery**.
>   The purpose is to reduce emissions."*

Will it be better to change it to:

> *"To avoid misunderstandings: the purpose of the component is not, **with a view to energy recovery**, to store electricity until needed. The purpose is to reduce emissions."*

?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to say.  What is the purpose of the component?

Comment: Why are you talking about what is not it's purpose? That's a bit weird. [Is it better to change it, not will]

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idiom to use. It's incorrect diction here and hard to understand.

Instead, use "for the purpose of":

> The purpose of the component would not be to store electricity until needed for the purpose of energy recovery.

Additionally, in technical writing, it is better to say what the purpose /is/, rather than what it is /not/, or to clearly say what it is first, and then what it is not:

> The purpose of the component is  _________, so it will not _________ until needed...

Certainly try to avoid "with a view to", it's awkward and confusing.